Does changing Google app callback url invalidates the current Access or Refresh tokens?
Suppose I am changing the Callback URL of the salesforce app, will it invalidate the access and refresh token of the salesforce app which were generated via the previous callback URL?

Refresh tokens are created based upon the Client id, client secrete and the user who granted access.
As long as you dont change those they will work.
